# Extracting data using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

I am doing Web-scraping in python. I have following data from which I just need to extract address.

```
# AMEEn # MT****29 Clinics:MYData Clinic 12345-123 rue bridge, QC B3D 1G3Phone: (123)123-1234 Email: sodth@gmail.com MYData Clinic 12345-123 rue bridge, QC B3D 1G3Phone: (123)123-1234
```

And my Logic is Following:

```
def getAddress(ent):
    addressEntry = re.search('(?<=Clinics:)(.*?)(?=Phone: )', ent)
    if addressEntry is None:
        return None
    return addressEntry.group(1)
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I believe it should be `(?<=Clinics:)`, not `(?<=Clincs:)`, a typo. You do not even need lookarounds here, just use `re.search(r'Clinics:(.*?)Phone: ', ent)`

Comment: Thats was my while posting this question.

Comment: @Ameen See my answer. You were misspelled Clinics as Clincs

Comment: yes, I saw @Anthony, but it did work in my code. I tried the same.

Comment: In that case what's the problem this time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you spelled `Clinics` wrong (you're missing the second 
"i") within your regex.

Try this as your regex:

```
'(?<=Clinics:)(.*?)(?=Phone: )'
```

[Test it here!](https://repl.it/Jo62/3)

Comment: It doesn't give any error but when I debug , my addressEntry is null.